# Triangular mesh containment

Tags: 3d

I'm trying to figure out a way to determine 3D mesh occlusion using projections for pre-processing.

Everything is fine for convex and even concave meshes, the issue is with meshes that contain holes (torus, teacup handle, etc). The question is how do you get a projection of, or even determine, a hole in a 3D mesh that you can use for determining visibility of objects behind.

For example, if I project all the triangles of a cutout cube, I get something like this:
[Cutout Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Wxc.png)

And then have a polygon that, if behind the cube would **not** be occluded, even though all points are within the mesh.
[Non-Occluded Overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao1s8.png)

*How can I determine if a polygon/triangle is completely overlapped by a triangular mesh with holes?*

Is there a way to quickly compute if an entire projected mesh is overlapped by another?

I'd like to avoid things like the z-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done by maintaining an auxiliary low-res conservative^ rasterization. If you absolutely want it to be vector-based, you can check if the projected contours^^ intersect, and if not, check if any point of the occludee is inside the occluder's projection. If they do intersect, there's no occlusion.
That said, I think general non-convex meshes without holes are not trivial either, since occlusion-wise there's little difference between C and O, for instance, apart from a (potentially arbitrarily small) region where C has a break.

^ "conservative" means that if any part of the pixel is touched, the entire pixel it marked

^^ contour consists only of the edges between front-facing and back-facing triangles. Ideally, one should also clip possible internal contours, but that's pretty expensive to do analytically, and it might be a better solution to just accept false non-occlusions.